# Laravel not responding with validator errors

Tags: json, laravel, validation, response, rules

I validate a model

`$validator = $c->validate($collection);`

This is the validate function

```
public function validate($data){
    return Validator::make($data, $this->rules());;
}
```

These are the rules

```
public function rules() {

    return  array([
        'name' => [
            'required', 'You need to choose a name for your collection.',
            'unique:collections,table_name', 'A collection or collection table with this name already exists'
        ],
           ...
        ]);
}
```

I'm trying to send back a JSON response with the validator's errors, as such:

```
return response()->json($validator->errors(), 200);
```

I'm currently testing validation for the 'name' rule, and the validator is failing, as expected.

However, I'm expecting it to return that rule's message ("A collection or collection table with this name already exists")

Instead, I'm getting this returned:

[image]

My goal is to have laravel send back the error that I need, thank you in advance for any help.

---

edit: updated code:

Messages:

```
public function messages(){
return [
'name.required' => 'A name must be specified for the collection',
'name.unique' => 'A collection or collection table with this name already exists',
'name.min' => 'The collection name is too short',
'fields.*.fieldName.unique' => 'Field names must be unique',
'fields.*.fieldName.required' => 'One or more fields must be specified for the collection',
'fields.*.fieldName.not_in' => 'Illegal field name, please try another one',
'fields.*.fieldName.min' => 'The field name is too short',
'fields.*.dataType.required' => 'A data-type must be specified for fields',
'fields.*.dataType.in' => 'Illegal data-type'
];
```

}

```
public function rules() {

    return  array([
        'name' => [
        'required', 'You need to choose a name for your collection.',
        'unique:collections,table_name', 'A collection or collection table 
with this name already exists',
        'min:2'
        ],
        'fields.*.fieldName' =>  
        [       
        'unique' => 'Please ensure that the fields are uniquely named.',
        'required' => 'You must specify a name for your fields.',
        'not_in:'.implode(',', self::$illegalFieldNames),
        'min:2'
        ],

        'fields.*.dataType' =>
        [
        'required', 'You must specify a data type for your fields.',
        'in:'.implode(',', self::$allowedDataTypes)
        ]

        ]);
}


public function validate($data){

    return Validator::make($data, $this->rules(), $this->messages());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator `make` method takes the third parameter as the messages array. You can't mix the rules and messages like that.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:collections,table_name'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'name.required' => 'You need to choose a name for your collection',
        'name.unique' => 'A collection or collection table with this name already exists',
    ];
}

public function validate($data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, $this->rules(), $this->messages());
}
```

Comment: Very well. But how would I be able to then know which error/message was actually returned?

Comment: Laravel gives you complete control on the error messages. Check out the documentation for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: Oh, so, the message value for the 'field.rule' index is automatically returned when that particular rule is breached?

Comment: @BarryD. yes. you need to define a custom message for each rule on a particular input. If needed, you can define a single message for all errors on an input as well.

Comment: Alright, I think my messages are organised, but I still have the original problem - the message that I want isn't being retrieved. I'm just getting the 0 field one.

Comment: updated it with current messages, rules, and the validation function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144814/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-barry-d).

Answer (score 0):

```
  $this->rules($request, array( 

            'name' => 
  'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts


            ));
```

use java script for revealing error

or you can use something like this .

```
public function store(Request $request)

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    // Store the blog post...
}
}
```